# Same data inserting over and over when refreshing page

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data from "product_table" to "daily_sale_report" but whenever I am refreshing the daily sale report page (where I am showing data which I inserted from product_table) everytime it's adding all data which previously added.but I want when I will add some new data in product_table only that data will be inserted.

MySQL code to data insert which I add in header

```
<?php
   include "database/db.php";

  $insert2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `daily_sale_report`(`product_id`, `date`, `time`) select `product_id`,`date`,`time`` from product_table where date = CURDATE()");


if(!$insert2){
    echo mysql_error();
}else{
    echo "";
};
```

and to data show, I use while loop

```
<?php
   $data_show = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `daily_sale_report`");
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($data_show))
   {
?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $data['date'];?></td>                                
    <td><?php echo $data['time'];?></td>
   </tr>

   <?php
    };
   ?>
```

Comment: Will this always be `1`? `cash_counter = '1'`

Comment: stop refreshing the page

Comment: because you are executing same query on every refresh

Comment: ok, how to stop that??

Comment: why do you keep reloading it anyway? looks like something that should jsut be run daily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a select in DB and check whether there are any rows related to CURDATE(). like `SELECT * FROM`daily_sale_report`WHERE`date`= CURDATE();`
If it does contain records ignore inserting, else insert .
(hope you insert only one row per day, if isn`t replace your condition in sql)
Example :

```
    include "database/db.php";

    $checkRecordExists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM daily_sale_report WHERE date= CURDATE()");
    if(empty($checkRecordExists)){
        $insert2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `daily_sale_report`(`product_id`, `date`, `time`) select `product_id`,`date`,`time`` from product_table where date = CURDATE()");
        if(!$insert2){
            echo mysql_error();
        }else{
            echo "";
        };
    }else{
        echo "record already there";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to update table daily_sale_report daily once for sales in cash counter 1.
You also need to include date filter to insert records only for that date.

Else the whole lot will be inserted to daily report.

Comment: where date = CURDATE() and cash_counter = '1'

Answer (score 0):

```
 $insert2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `daily_sale_report`(`product_id`, `date`, `time`) select `product_id`,`date`,`time`` from product_table where date = CURDATE()");
```

== Example  insert ABC to tableA <= Find ABC in tableB Where day is today

let say today 2017-12-14 0910 i insert product name="hello1", then i close

when today 0915 u open this page , u current day time is 2017-12-14 0915 it is still in 2017-12-14 so it will reinsert the data that i insert just now , and it will keep repeat one hv ppl this page , until 2017-12-15  it will stop clone 2017-12-14 data

hope this will help u